# F# - create list with conditional elements

Tags: list, f#

Consider this code

```
let a, b, c = ...
let mutable l = [a]

if conditionB then l <- b :: l
if conditionC then l <- c :: l
```

I feel as this goes against the language principles. Is this the correct way or am I missing something?

Edit:
`l` is then just returned as a result

Comment: You should add some context about where/when/how `l` is used

Comment: If you are asking a codereview question, ask it on codereview

Comment: I didn't know such a stack exists.

Comment: Well, you might have good reasons for writing it this way. But generally you should try avoid returning unit(), and mutating the list. For example you could just write a function that takes an item and a list and returns a new list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sequence expressions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/sequences) are quite practical for this purpose.

```
[ 
    if conditionC then yield c
    if conditionB then yield b
    yield a
]
```

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to say without seeing the code in a larger context - but given just this snippet, you can avoid using mutation by defining a new version of the list with a different name:

```
let a, b, c = ...
let l1 = [a]
let l2 = if conditionB then b :: l1 else l1
let l3 = if conditionC then c :: l2 else l2
```

Here, we first define `l1` which contains just the element `a`. Then we define a new lists `l2` and `l3`, which contain additional elements depending on whether `conditionB` or `conditionC` holds (if none of them hold, we just copy reference to the original list `l1` two times).

F# also has a feature called *variable shadowing* which lets you reuse the same name and hide the original value, so you could actually reuse the same name `l` for your lists - the following means exactly the same as the above code:

```
let a, b, c = ...
let l = [a]
let l = if conditionB then b :: l else l
let l = if conditionC then c :: l else l
```

And you can drop the last `let l =` if you just want to return the final list as the result.

Comment: One complication - you could have both conditions be true